# Opencost distributes total price for computation nodes across namespaces or it calculates the unit price and multiplies it by used resources?

Tags: kubernetes

Imagine I have a simple Kubernetes cluster with 1 namespace and 1 pod running and I want to call `allocation/compute` endpoint of opencost API inside it.
Would I have a different result in case my cluster either baked by 2 computation nodes or 1 computation node? (as a cluster owner I pay price per node, not per a used resources)

Same question but from another angle: in case I have empty kubernetes cluster, would Opencost give me a `total_cost` equal to what I actually pay for my computation nodes or it would give me zero?